# ROR3 : hidden_field security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, hidden-field

**i've this in _form.html.erb:**

```
        <%if current_user.role_id == 1 %>

            <div class="combo_box">
                <%= f.label :subscriber %>
                <%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all,:id,:name,{:include_blank=>false}, :class => 'styled')  %>
            </div>

            <div class="combo_box">
                <%= f.label :group %>
                <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:group_id, User.all,:support_agent_groups,:name,:id,:name, {:prompt => "-- Select a group --"}, :class => 'styled')  %>
            </div>

            <div class="combo_box">
                <%= f.label :role %>
                <%= f.collection_select(:role_id, Role.all,:id,:name,{:include_blank=>false}, {:class => 'styled'})  %>
            </div>

            <div class="combo_box">
                <%= f.label :subscription %>
                <%= f.collection_select(:subscription_id, Subscription.all,:id,:name, {:prompt => "-- Select a subscription --"}, {:class=>'styled'})    %>
            </div>              

        <% elsif  current_user.role_id == 6  && @user.role_id != 6 %>

            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

            <%= f.hidden_field :subscription_id, :value => current_user.subscription_id %>


            <div class="combo_box">
                <%= f.label :group %>
                <%= f.collection_select(:group_id, SupportAgentGroup.where(:user_id => current_user.id),:id,:name, {:prompt => "-- Select a group --"}, :class => 'styled')  %>
            </div>
            <div class="combo_box">
                <%= f.label :role %>
                <%= f.collection_select(:role_id, Role.where('id <> ?', 1).where('id <> ?', 6),:id,:name,{:include_blank=>false}, {:class => 'styled'})  %>
            </div>

        <% elsif  current_user.role_id == 6 %>

            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :role_id, :value => current_user.role_id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :subscription_id, :value => current_user.subscription_id %>


            <div class="combo_box">
                <%= f.label :group %>
                <%= f.collection_select(:group_id, SupportAgentGroup.where(:user_id => current_user.id),:id,:name, {:prompt => "-- Select a group --"}, :class => 'styled')  %>
            </div>

        <% else %>

            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.user.id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => current_user.group_id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :subscription_id, :value => current_user.user.subscription_id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :role_id, :value => current_user.role_id %>

        <% end %>
```

I can view every hidden filed with values on inspect element with firebug option in browser as

```
<input id="user_user_id" type="hidden" value="2" name="user[user_id]" />
```

where I can change value `2` to `100/200/....`

and on submint the new value `100/200/...` is posted for saving to db and was saved in db.

Am i need to check all the conditions in view and also in controller to find the suitable default values.. or any option to use the hidden_filed to fix this security issue.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2):

No don't need to pass user_id,you can get current_user from controller

Answer (score 1):

As Amar says you don't need to pass the user id from controller to controller, because you can get it with the `current_user` method from the session variables.

Keep in mind, that you cannot trust the data received from the user, everything can be forged.